# Google+ share link with "%20" not working

Tags: google-plus, share

```html
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://www.utp.edu.my/The%20University/SitePages/Home.aspx" target="_blank" class="share-btn google-plus">
    google share
</a>
```

Cannot read the url link correctly:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink) suggests, the URL needs to be url encoded. So your URL will look like: `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.utp.edu.my%2FThe%2520University%2FSitePages%2FHome.aspx`

And then your link will look like:

```html
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.utp.edu.my%2FThe%2520University%2FSitePages%2FHome.aspx" target="_blank" class="share-btn google-plus">
    google share
</a>
```